# How to show Cropped image in ImageView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, vision

I am trying to get the bounding box values for the faces in image and crop out the faces in the bounding box. I am able to get and draw the bounding box successfully but am unable to crop the images out and show them in the Image View. Can anyone please guide me on where I am going wrong? Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1. Load Default Image
        guard let image = UIImage(named: "anuj.jpeg") else {return}
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.detectFaces(img: image)
    }



    @IBAction func modeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn{
            print("Camera Mode ON !!")
        }
        else{
            print("Camera Mode OFF !!")
        }
    }


    // *******************************************************************
    // 2. Function to detect faces in Image and retrun Bounding Box Values
    // *******************************************************************
    func detectFaces(img: UIImage){
        // Get Image Scaled Height
        let imageScaledHeight = view.frame.width / (img.size.width) * (img.size.height)
        // Create Face Detection Request
        let request = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest { (req, err)
            in
            if let err = err{
                print("Failed to detect faces !! \(err)")
                return
            }
            print("Request: \(req)")

            req.results?.forEach({ (res) in
                // Get face observations
                guard let faceObservation = res as? VNFaceObservation else {return}

                // Print detected face bounding box values
                print("Face Observations: \(faceObservation.boundingBox)")

                // Create Bounding Box
                let x = self.view.frame.width * faceObservation.boundingBox.origin.x
                let width = self.view.frame.width * faceObservation.boundingBox.width
                let height = imageScaledHeight * faceObservation.boundingBox.height
                let y = imageScaledHeight * (1 - faceObservation.boundingBox.origin.y) - height

                // Show bounding Box
                let redView = UIView()
                redView.backgroundColor = .red
                redView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
                redView.alpha = 0.4
                self.view.addSubview(redView)

                // Crop Face in Red View i.e. in Bounding Box and show in Image View
                let crop = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
                let image = img.cgImage?.cropping(to: crop)
                let cropImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(cgImage: image!))
                self.view.addSubview(cropImageView)
            })
        }

        // Convert Image to cgImage and pass to request handler
        let cgImage = img.cgImage
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage!, options: [:])
        // Perform vision request
        do{
            try handler.perform([request])
        }
        catch let reqErr{
            print("Failed to perform request: \(reqErr)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "am unable to crop the images out" What do you mean "unable to"? What is actually happening? What's the problem you experience with your code?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307181/uiimage-getting-rotated-90-degrees-after-cropping

Comment: Hi @matt, by saying unable to crop images out, I mean that running this code, I am able to see the original image with the red bounding box on top in the imageview. But when I add the code to crop out just the face in the bounding box as an image and display that in the ImageView, I get an empty screen. I checked the size of the cropped image and that looks fine as well. I think it's a small problem but where. I am a bit new to iOS development so was trying to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: The _size_ of the cropped image may be fine, but the _content_ may not be. Why don't you debug? Put a breakpoint on `self.view.addSubview(cropImageView)` and _look_ at the image and the image view while paused in the debugger. Then continue on and use the view debugger to _look_ at what's happened to your image view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably this line:

```
let image = img.cgImage?.cropping(to: crop)
```

That is *not* how to crop a UIImage, because a UIImage, along with everything else drawn on your screen, has a *scale*, and it has an *orientation*, but a CGImage does not.

To crop a UIImage, draw it into a properly scaled graphics image context so that the desired region of the image falls into the context, and extract the resulting image.